# Facebook graph API not returing any data for some edges like albums,accounts,feeds and friends

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing Facebook Graph API and I am getting desired response for following queries.

```
       dynamic fbProfileInfo = await fb.GetTaskAsync("me?fields=first_name,last_name,link,locale,email,name,birthday,gender,location,age_range".GraphAPICall(fb_appsecret_proof));

        //get current picture
       dynamic fbProfileImgResult = await fb.GetTaskAsync("{0}/picture?width=100&height=100&redirect=false".GraphAPICall((string)fbProfileInfo.id,fb_appsecret_proof));
```

But for the the queries that involving edges I am not getting any data for the reponse.I am putting a example of one of such queries.

```
dynamic myInfo = await fb.GetTaskAsync(string.Format("me/albums?fields=id,name, count, link," + "picture, privacy").GraphAPICall(fb_appsecret_proof);
```

Comment: Well did you have the user grant your app the necessary permission(s) first ...?

Comment: @CBroe How can I grant necessary permission?Through Facebook developer account or through the Facebook account of the user?

Comment: You ask for them during login.